# Why does the stackpanel ignore Orientation property?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I'd like to use a stackpanel with two textblock that have two uris, inside a ContentDialog. The problem is that despite I set the property to Vertical, it has no effect and that's the visual result

[image: ContentDialog with messed up StackPanel]

```
private async void AboutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {       
        TextBlock gHRepoTB = new TextBlock();
        Hyperlink hyperlink1 = new Hyperlink();
        Run run1 = new Run();
        run1.Text = "View GitHub repository";
        hyperlink1.NavigateUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");
        hyperlink1.Inlines.Add(run1);
        gHRepoTB.Inlines.Add(hyperlink1);
        TextBlock privacyPolicyTB = new TextBlock();
        Hyperlink hyperlink2 = new Hyperlink();
        Run run2 = new Run();
        run2.Text = "Privacy Policy";
        hyperlink2.NavigateUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com/");
        hyperlink2.Inlines.Add(run2);
        gHRepoTB.Inlines.Add(hyperlink2);
        StackPanel aboutPanel = new StackPanel();
        aboutPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        aboutPanel.Children.Add(gHRepoTB);
        aboutPanel.Children.Add(privacyPolicyTB);
        ContentDialog aboutDialog = new ContentDialog();            
        aboutDialog.Title = "About";
        aboutDialog.Content = aboutPanel;
        aboutDialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Report a bug";
        aboutDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += ReportBug_Click;
        aboutDialog.PrimaryButtonStyle = App.Current.Resources["AccentButtonStyle"] as Style;
        aboutDialog.CloseButtonText = "Close";
        await aboutDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: The `StackPanel` is fine. You are constructing your `TextBlock` objects incorrectly. Next time you want to post a question here: 1) please make some effort to provide a [mcve], 2) **debug your code**...surely if you'd just step through the code and take a look at each object as it's being constructed and added to the panel, you'd have seen the problem, 3) use XAML to construct your UI, so that copy/paste goof-ups like this don't occur in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I have already debugged my code and provide an example to easily reproduce that. Can you tell me what's the problem with TextBlock objects since the URIs work?

Comment: You know you can just set the content of the hyperlinkbutton to a string? That way you will be able to clean up your code a lot, whilst enabling you to spot your typo. Or use XAML as Peter suggests

Comment: Found the typo, but can I know why using XAML is recommended for this scenario?

Comment: @MarcAnt01 Then you'll see the layout before you run the code, it looks cleaner, XAML is especially meant for static UI (which this is), and you'll have room in you AboutButton_Click event for more useful code since you only have to call `await new AboutDialog().ShowAsync();`. If you dont want to use XAML and create the content for the contentdialog in code, please reply and I'll post an answer which uses less code and is way clearer.

Comment: I'd rather use code behind to keep just the essential elements in mainpage.xaml. I'd be happy to be suggested a cleaner solution anyway

Comment: @MarcAnt01 see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the second `Hyperlink` to the wrong `TextBlock`. It should be `privacyPolicyTB.Inlines.Add(hyperlink2);`:

```
TextBlock privacyPolicyTB = new TextBlock();
Hyperlink hyperlink2 = new Hyperlink();
Run run2 = new Run();
run2.Text = "Privacy Policy";
hyperlink2.NavigateUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com/");
hyperlink2.Inlines.Add(run2);
privacyPolicyTB.Inlines.Add(hyperlink2); //<-- here
```

Comment: Ah, yeah this was the problem. I thought it was due to the property not working properly, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

@mm8 showed how to fix your problem, however this is the result of unnecessary and unclear code.

Here are the things I changed:

- I've changed a button with hyperlink layout to a [hyperlinkbutton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton?view=winrt-19041).
- I've set the contents to just a string since in this case no more is needed.
- Instead of manually setting a style to the primarybutton, I've specified the `DefaultButton`

By creating the dialog this way, you are less prone to making mistakes, others and yourself later on will be able to tell faster what's going on, and less temporary variables are introduced.

The code *(You should be able to copy this code directly over your current eventhandler)*:

```cs
private async void AboutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel aboutPanel = new StackPanel();
    aboutPanel.Children.Add(
        new HyperlinkButton
        {
            Content = "View GitHub repository",
            NavigateUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/")
        });
    aboutPanel.Children.Add(
        new HyperlinkButton
        {
            Content = "Privacy Policy",
            NavigateUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com/")
        });

    var dlg = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "About",
        Content = aboutPanel,
        PrimaryButtonText = "Report a bug",
        DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary,
        CloseButtonText = "Close"
    };
    dlg.PrimaryButtonClick += ReportBug_Click;
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

See the result below:
[image: see the result below]